# Selection sort, number of actions

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I need to get number of comparison actions and number of copying actions. It should be about ~4. By this formula, but I'm getting it about ~2 (my n is 2, so it should be 2^2=4). What's wrong?

```
void selection(double A[], int N)
{
    int i, j, min, tmp;
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
            if (A[j] < A[min]) {
                noofcomparison++;
                min = j;
            }
            if (min != i)
            {
                noofcomparison++;
                tmp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[min];
                A[min] = tmp;
                noofcopying += 3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full code: https://repl.it/repls/WobblyMountainousDegus

Comment: [OT]: C++ use 0-indexing for array, so your loop should begin at `i = 0` instead of `i = 1`.

Comment: @Jozikas Nice question! Like @Abdullah mentioned, you don't actually need to do ```noofcomparison++``` inside if statement, if you move it outside if statement, it should yield the correct result. You are only counting the number of comparisons when ```(A[j] < A[min])``` whereas you are doing a comparison every loop regardless if the condition is true or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `noofcomparison++` inside `if` statement. Your code doesn't increment `noofcomparison` when comparison results `false`. You need to move `noofcomparison++` outside of `if` statements.